# Calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I have to add the no of delays to calendar type , and wants the new date in Calendar Type only.

```
limitDate = orderDate + settlementDelay.
```

where

```
limitDate = java.util.Calendar

orderDate = java.util.Calendar

settlementDelay = int
```

I tried something like this :

```
Calendar limitDate = order.getOrderDate().add(Calendar.DATE,settlementDelay);
```

But its giving me the

```
Type mismatch error: Cannot convert from void to Calendar.
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 5):

You're getting this error because [Calendar#add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method doesn't return anything (see void) and adds the input date/month/year etc in the supplied Calendar instance itself.

**EDIT:** If you really need a new instance then use code like this:

```
Calendar limitDate = Calendar.getInstance();
limitDate.setTime( orderDate.getTime() );
limitDate.add(Calendar.DATE, settlementDelay);
```

Comment: Yes..I know but i would like to have the orderDate+ settlementDelay  should return me new Calendar

Comment: See my edit section for getting a new Calendar instance with day addition.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library instead.

It's far better for date manipulations.
It does has the plusDays method you seem to want.

```
DateTime orderDate = ...;
DateTime limitDate = orderDate.plusDays(settlementDelay);
```